# Unable to get data form <li> _data_ </li> and using python, I m making web scraper

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is a follow up, question on the question which I asked earlier and got a very good answer, but, that code, I didn't understand fully the program. Please help me to scrape information from the following websites.

1. https://premieragile.com/csm-training/
2. https://www.simplilearn.com/agile-and-scrum/csm-certification-training

Here i want all the information given in each card. Also, adding the program I am using, which i got from stackoverflow itself.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://premieragile.com/csm-training/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for row in soup.select(".row > schedules-courses br-10 h-100 p-3 p-sm-4"):
    date = row.findAll(".d-flex align-items-center pb-4 h6").text.strip()
#     year = row.select_one(".li .batchDetails .date-details .date span").text.strip()
#     rating = row.select_one(".imdbRating").text.strip()
    # ...other variables

    all_data.append([date])


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["date"])
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

here, please explain how I should add div class in the 'for loop', also, what will be the hierarchy of the

1. div
2. li
3. h
4. ul
5. li

Please help me understand this, I got the general idea that we are crating empty list and adding data in those using beautiflSoup object. I am utterly confused in how I should study the website I want to scrape and thus, how to add column in the row of the program.

P.S I m getting blank output.

Comment: Focusing your question on a single issue would be great - Content is dynamically loaded from another resource. It do not contain in your soup, thats why you get an empty output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content is dynamically loaded from another resource. It do not contain in your soup, thats why you get an empty output.

Simply load it from this resource https://premieragile.com/csm-training/?page=1&id=ol&city=&countryCode=DE&trainerid=undefined&timezone=Europe/Berlin and adjust parameters for your needs.

```
url = "https://premieragile.com/csm-training/?page=1&id=ol&city=&countryCode=DE&trainerid=undefined&timezone=Europe/Berlin"
```

HMTL is wrapped in JSON structur so you have to specify the path from that the `BeautifulSoup` object should be created from.

```
r = requests.get(url, headers={'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}).json()['html']
```

##### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "https://premieragile.com/csm-training/?page=1&id=ol&city=&countryCode=DE&trainerid=undefined&timezone=Europe/Berlin"

r = requests.get(url, headers={'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}).json()['html']

soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

all_data = []
for e in soup.select('.loop'):
    all_data.append({
        'trainer':e.h6.text.strip(),
        'date': ' '.join(s.strip() for s in e.li.text.split('\n'))
    })
all_data

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

##### Output

| trainer | date |
| --- | --- |
| Daniel James Gullo | 08 Jul - 08 Jul - 2022 |
| Raj Kasturi | 11 Jul - 13 Jul - 2022 |
| Michel Goldenberg | 11 Jul - 12 Jul - 2022 |
| Valerio Zanini | 12 Jul - 14 Jul - 2022 |
| Michael Franken | 13 Jul - 15 Jul - 2022 |

Comment: Suppose, I want to fetch 'pricing' details form the same website, now, pricing is stored in the following div class,  d-flex align-items-end --> h, what will be the logic for coding this?  Because, prince and timing both are mentioned in heading tab, how will the program know that which heading tab, I am talking about?

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - But to give you a hint `e.h6.text.strip()` selects only the first `h6` , so you have to select the price in  combination of tag and class.

Comment: I tied, didn't got results, the combination that i used for getting the price is given below, here the class is the 'new-courses-cl' and price is stored in h6 tag.  
for e in soup.select('.loop'):
    all_data.append({
        'trainer':e.h6.text.strip(),
        'date': ' '.join(s.strip() for s in e.li.text.split('\n')),
        'timing': ('h6',{'class':'new-courses-cl'}).text.strip()
    }) .......  please tell me how to write the div class and tag for any of the one column. FYI, i m not getting result.

Comment: You are not trying to find anything ->  `'timing': e.find('h6',{'class':'new-courses-cl'}).text.strip()`

Comment: Where you find this URL: https://premieragile.com/csm-training/?page=1&id=ol&city=&countryCode=DE&trainerid=undefined&timezone=Europe/Berlin ??

Comment: Open the website in chrome and open developertools (F12) and select network section. press F5 to reload the page and check the xhr requests. Its preview of response will contain the HTML

Comment: what is xhr request?